# How to get a div-container into a tooltip

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

i want to use ui-tooltip. But I do not know, how to get a div-container with an id=test123 on mouseover into a ui-tooltip.

```js
$('.info-sign').tooltip({
  items: "[data-tooltip]",
  content: function() {
    return $(this).attr("data-tooltip");
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 68%;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.container>div {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container header {
  background: #EAEAEA;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}

.container footer {
  background: #EAEAEA;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<div class="info-sign" data-tooltip="<p>ciao 1</p>">i1</div>
<div class="info-sign" data-tooltip="<p>ciao2</p>">i2</div>
<div class="info-sign">i3</div>

<div class="container" id="test123">
  <header>Überschrift</header>
  <div>Jahr</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
  <div>Jahr</div>
  <div>Beschreibung</div>
  <footer>Unterschrift</footer>
</div>
```

Thanks for help, Cap

Comment: Please put all relevant code in the question. A fiddle is helpful, but if their site goes down your question will be unanswerable. I've edited it in for you, this time.

Comment: Thanks for editing. I also was on editing my post, but you were faster.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```js
$('.info-sign').tooltip({
  items: "[data-tooltip]",
  content: function() {
    return $('#' + $(this).data('target')).html();
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 68%;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  padding: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.container>div {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container header {
  background: #EAEAEA;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}

.container footer {
  background: #EAEAEA;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<div class="info-sign" data-target="test1" data-tooltip="<p>ciao 1</p>">i1</div>
<div class="info-sign" data-target="test2" data-tooltip="<p>ciao2</p>">i2</div>
<div class="info-sign" data-target="test3" data-tooltip="">i3</div>

<div class="container" id="test1">
  <header>Überschrift</header>
  <div>Para 1</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
  <div>Jahr</div>
  <div>Beschreibung</div>
  <footer>Unterschrift</footer>
</div>

<div class="container" id="test2">
  <header>Überschrift</header>
  <div>Para 2</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
  <div>Jahr</div>
  <div>Beschreibung</div>
  <footer>Unterschrift</footer>
</div>

<div class="container" id="test3">
  <header>Überschrift</header>
  <div>Para 3</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit</div>
  <div>Jahr</div>
  <div>Beschreibung</div>
  <footer>Unterschrift</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: No, of course not.
You hardcoded the id into the content function.

Comment: No, of course not.
You hardcoded the id into the content function. I wanted to find an entry for data-tooltip, that loads the div with the id "test123". For example like <button class='tooltip' data-tooltip-content='#test123'>...